# TCL: how to execute program using enviorment PATH variable

Tags: variables, path, tcl, exe, environment

I've got following line in my script

exec $::env(PATH)/program.exe

In my env PATH variable I've got a directory where I've got this executable file. For example: 
PATH env variable got among other this - D:\my_program\bin

I've got error:

Error:

```
couldn't execute C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;D:\my_program\bin;\program": no such file or directory
```

Any suggest how to execute .exe file using system variable like PATH in tcl?

Thanks

PS 
OK, when I've create a new env variable (PATH1 - without any other paths, just one) and set .exe file path to it, it seems to work. Any solution to do with PATH (with multiple paths) excluding set D:\my_program\bin in first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply use the Tcl library function made for this `auto_execok`.

Try this:

```
exec {*}[auto_execok program.exe]
```

It automatically searches the PATH and constructs the right path for using with exec.

For example, to start notepad.exe:

```
% auto_execok notepad.exe
C:/windows/system32/notepad.exe
% exec {*}[auto_execok notepad.exe]
```

To see why the {*} is needed, have a look at http://wiki.tcl.tk/765. Basically `auto_execok` is pretty smart and can return a list, if needed, e.g. for running `start` on windows, which needs the expansion to work properly with exec.